# Carolina reaper leaves turning brownish and veiny

Tags: identification, plant-health

I planted 2 seeds about 3 weeks ago and the plant seemed to grow pretty much okay then the leaves started to turn kinda Brown and now it stopped completely it's growth. They almost have full sun all day, maybe it's too much? [image: Image here of how it looks]

Comment: How hot is it getting near the pots? Have fertilized? If so, how much of what? Peppers will stop growing if they get too much nitrogen, however that does not usually make for brown veins. How often watered? Drainage? What's the soil? Peppers don't much like peat moss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see, but that looks like mould. I also notice that the out-of-focus potting medium looks very dark, which is not in itself an issue, but most composts tend to appear darker when wet.

So my first thought is - how much are you watering these plants? Chilli peppers are from hot, and often fairly dry climates, and are not fond of an abundance of water. These are young to go very long without water, but being on the cusp of wilting before being given more would be absolutely fine for these. They also look to be in a planter. Do the pots have drainage holes in the bottom? If not, you must be very careful not to have any water pooling in the bottom of the pot - as you can't see this, the only way to judge this is by common sense and erring on the side of too dry.

Comment: I think to problem is I overwatered them too much. Also the soil I bought for the pepper is specifically made for the Carolina reaper (at least that's what was written on the bag).